# Container view child viewcontrollers segue is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicontainerview

I have tried to make my own scrollable tabs in iOS and for that i have used UIContainerView. Scrollable tabs are working fine. Each child view controller is having `UITableView` and when i call segue on

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for each child view controllers, it work for only one child view controller, rest other child view controllers it is not working..

**'Could not find a navigation controller for segue ''.**

Please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

Place you child view controllers in a UINavigationController. Something like:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:childViewController];
```

Then put navController in your container view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I simply added the child view controllers by following statement.
earlier i have added 
    [self.containerView addSubview:fifthChildVC.view];

but now i have added this too and it is working fine.
[self addChildViewController:fifthChildVC];

can any one help me out what is the disadvantage of this.